# Proof of a Logical Statement.

Tags: solution-verification

Prove that $A \cap B$ is a subset of $A$.

Would I go around this by saying that $S \subseteq A$ and then by hypothesis belongs to $B$ as well?

Or would I do it with values of $X$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $C$, per definition, means that every element of $A$ is an element of $C$. Since for every element $x$ of $A \cap B$, $x$ is an element of $A$, this shows the required.